# Como saber os argumentos contidos no '...' numa função em R?

Tags: r

Em R pode ser usado '...' para que a função receba um número indeterminado de argumentos.

Como fazer para saber quais argumentos foram usados na função?

Exemplo, se eu quisesse imprimir os argumentos usados.

```
imprimeArgumentos <- function(...) {
  args <- #pega os argumentos contidos em ´...´
  print(args)
}
```

A função deve funcionar da seguinte maneira.

```
imprimeArgumentos(x=3, z=NULL, y=3) 

$x
[1] 3

$z
NULL

$y
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma forma simples de capturar os argumentos é colocá-los em uma lista:

```
imprimeArgumentos <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  print(args)
}

imprimeArgumentos(x=3, z=NULL, y=3) 
#> $x
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $z
#> NULL
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] 3
```

Se você quiser trabalhar com lazy evaluation, você pode usar `substitute` e apenas fazer o evaluation dos argumentos quando oportuno:

```
imprimeArgumentos <- function(...) {
   # vai te retornar uma expressão da lista e não a lista em si
  args <- substitute(list(...))
  print(args)
}
imprimeArgumentos(x=3, z, y=3)
#> list(x = 3, z, y = 3)
```

Note que neste último exemplo, `z` não existe, mas função não dá erro pois ainda não avaliamos o conteúdo da lista.